# How to limit the columns of the select statement?

Tags: sql, select

I have to create a new table and inside should be the columns I get from the CASE statement. I do not need the rest of the columns resulting from the select statement

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test
AS (
SELECT a.id, ...
CASE WHEN a.id = 1 THEN 2
ELSE 0 
END as LegalType
FROM table a, ...
WHERE ...);
```

now my question how can I select only the column LegalType from the CASE statement? I do not want to have column a.id

Comment: Simply don't select a.id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can SELECT INTO

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.id = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END as LegalType
       ....
INTO   test
FROM   table a
WHERE  1=1);
```

This will create you a table based on the data returned in the SELECT. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188029.aspx